# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]:

Tags: html, frontend, gulp, scss

Здраствуйте! Только начал изучать gulp для более быстрой верстки, и уже возникла проблема (((
Вот код:

```
const {src, dest} = require('gulp')
const sass = require('gulp-sass')
const csso = require('gulp-csso')
const include = require('gulp-file-include')
const htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin')
const del = require('del')
const sync = require('browser-sync').create()

function html() {
  return src('src/**.html')
  .pipe(include({
    prefix: '@@'
  }))
  .pipe(dest('dist'))
}

exports.html = html
```

И выдает такую ошибку:

```
Yaroslav@DESKTOP-BS02H8M MINGW64 ~/Desktop/gulp-html
$ gulp html
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\Yaroslav\Desktop\gulp-html\node_modules\del\index.js from C:\Users\Yaroslav\Desktop\gulp-html\gulpfile.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\Yaroslav\Desktop\gulp-html\gulpfile.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Yaroslav\Desktop\gulp-html\gulpfile.js:6:13) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Читал что это связано с новой версией gulp'a, и нужно использовать импорты, или что-то вроде того. Менял версию, нода и все нужное установлено. Все равно не работает (((

Если не сложно, объясните в чём проблема и перепишите код правильно, буду очень благодарен ^^